# how to target specific input for posting with requests or requests_html

Tags: python-3.x, curl, python-requests

i need to fill a unique input here 
https://outline.com/
when i do ctrl+U with firefox, the id is hidden by some js effect i think, in my opinion the id is 'source' but how can i see it and target it for posting ?

it tried this:

```
import requests, requests_html
import json
url_out = "https://outline.com/"
url_target = "https://www.whatyouwanthere"

r = requests.post(url_out, data=json.dumps(url_target))
```

is it possible to avoid selenium for this task ?

Answer (score 0):

You were pretty far from the actual solution, but there are definitely more ways to do this.

This works:

```
import requests, json
url_out = "http://outline-server-788914346.us-west-2.elb.amazonaws.com/article"
url_target = "https://www.google.com"

r = requests.get(url = url_out, params = {'source_url': url_target})
data = r.json() 

print(data)
```

I was able to find this by watching the network activity in devtools and taking a look at the app.js file in use on their site. The form on the main page just queries an API with the article URL and the API is what generates the short url on their service.

Honestly, I'm not sure if this breaks their ToS or not, you may want to check with them on that.

Comment: did you try before normal use of this link : https://outline.com/

Comment: `requests.post` or `requests.get` aren't going to send data to a _form_, it will send data to a receiving method, usually a server-side location that receives the data and processes it. If you take a look at most `form` tags on a site, you'll see an `action`, this path is what is actually processing the form data. If you want to automate the filling out of the form, you would have to use something like selenium.